# Typescript - Jest: Mock indirect function call

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

Let's say I have two files, that contain the following functions:

`file-a.ts`:

```
import { fnB1 } from "./file-b";

export function fnA(): number { return fnB1(); }
```

`file-b.ts`:

```
export function fnB1(): number { return fnB2(); }
export function fnB2(): number { return 5; }
```

To summarize it's like this:

[image]

In my test file `file-test.ts`, I now want to test `fnA` but I want to mock `fnB2` to not return `5` but to return `42`. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a possible solution:

`file-test.ts`:

```
import { fnA } from "./file-a";
import * as FileB from "./file-b";

it('should work', () => {
   jest.spyOn(FileB, 'fnB2').mockReturnValue(42);

   expect(fnA()).toBe(42);
}
```

But in order to make this work, I had to change `file-b.ts`. I had to add a `exports.` in front of the function call:

```
export fnB1() { return exports.fnB2(); }
export fnB2() { return 5; }
```